# Using stemming in K-Means clustering

Tags: algorithm, k-means, stemming

I am trying to implement [K-Means Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) and am confused about the vector part.

This is what i did :

For each document, i generated tf-idf for each word in it and stored that in a STL map. Then used cosine similarity for the algorithm with the actual words.

Where should i use the stemming part ?

Should i first stem the words and calculated the tf-idf of the stemmed words ?

Should i use only stemmed words for the algorithm ?

Would using stemming not degrade the results ?

Comment: See http://home.deib.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/kmeans.html

Comment: @user1929959 there is no mention of stemming on this page.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what your clustering objectives are.
In a project we once did, we needed to provide a match score between two strings with possible variations on the words.  We first stemmed, and then counted the number of matching words between the strings.  If this type of matching makes sense in your problem, then stemming first is probably a good idea.
Of course you lose information when you stem, but you gain the ability to reduce some noise.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, stemming is done before actually computing the tf-idf for each stem.

Then for your last two questions, I'd say it depends on what you're doing. You should try different method (stemming, raw words, lemmatization) and see what method yields the best results.

In the case of clustering, you should use an set of annotated documents, try your methods on it, and then establish for each method its [confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix), which will help you determine the best method for your problem.